# nextjs app rerenders on routing to any page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth, next-router

I am using nextjs version `12.1.6`, react-dom version `18.0.5`, next-auth 4.6.1, I have an application with 2 routes at the moment, an index page and a login page, when I route from the index page to the login page and vice versa, my whole app rerenders, I have react-profiler and the given reason is context change, I assume its have to do something with the `SessionProvider` from `next-auth` but why it rerenders my whole app?

[image]

as you can see I have a HeaderComponent that did NOT rerendered, this is because I used `React.memo` on it, but I dont want to wrap all my components in `React.memo`, also this component is used inside on a Layout component `pages/_app.tsx`

my _app.tsx

```js
function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
          <title>foo</title>
          <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
  
      <SessionProvider session={ pageProps.session }>
        <LayoutComponent>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </LayoutComponent>  
      </SessionProvider>  
    </>    
  );
}
```

also I am using nextjs `Link` jsx element for routing

my LayoutComponent:

```js
const LayoutComponent = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
    return (
        <>
            <HeaderComponent 
                homePath='/'
                signinPath='/auth/signin'
                aboutPath='/about'
            />
                <main>
                    { children }
                </main>
            <FooterComponent />
        </>
    );
}

export default LayoutComponent;
```

Comment: It is hard to tell without your login/index page code

Comment: I have nothing there, literally h1 tag with the message "this is the login page"

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'll give it a shot.

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

Component in the code above is your page (Login/Index). Whenever you navigate to a page from another one by clicking a Next Js link, your Login/Index component will be fetched from the server and then React will compare the new and old component and re-render since they are different.

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <VerticalLayout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </VerticalLayout>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

If you put your page component between opening an closing tags of a layout component like above, only the corresponding component will be re-render again but VerticalLayout will stay untouched.

```
const VerticalLayout = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div id="layout-wrapper">
      <HeaderComponent />
      <main>
        <Sidebar />
        <div className="main-content">{children}</div>
      </main>
      <FooterComponent />
    </div>
  )
})
```

You can then place your header/footer components in that component like above. So that they will not be re-render when you navigate to a different page.

Comment: Hi, nope, didn't work, I edited my question, and added my `pages/_app.tsx` content

Comment: Your code looks different than mine. I shared an example with one wrapping component in which I put the rest such as header and footer.

Comment: yeah but I am using `next-auth` so I need that SessionProvider wrapper

Comment: @AhmetFiratKeler's answer worked for me.

Here's a shortened version of his answer:

- `<Component />` renders whatever is on the active page. [Learn more](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app).

- Use `<VerticalLayout>` only in the `MyApp` component to wrap `<Component />`. Rather than using it on every page to wrap the pages' elements.

- Move whatever you wish to persist between route changes into `<VerticalLayout>`.

By so doing, when you route to a new page, `<VerticalLayout>`'s content will remain intact. While `<Component />` will display the new page's items.